# Warnings & Errors when launching Emacs from WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, emacs

I have a WSL Ubuntu system with *systemd* enabled. I also configured `snap` and installed my `Emacs` using snap.

When I start Emacs from WSL console, I can see the GUI and use Emacs. But I got the following errors and messages.

The Emacs instance seems to be fully functional. So, I think the errors/warnings are not critical. But I wonder if I can fix or disable whatever function triggers them.

```
(emacs:587975): dbind-WARNING **: 18:37:34.363: AT-SPI: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files

(emacs:587975): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 18:37:34.405: g_settings_schema_source_lookup: assertion 'source != NULL' failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Short answer:*

```
sudo apt install gvfs at-spi2-core
```

*More detail:*

The error messages are due to a few missing D-bus services.  Usually, these services would be installed with and started under the Desktop environment (Ubuntu Desktop/Gnome, Xfce4, etc.), but that doesn't happen in WSL.  WSL's "desktop" is really Windows itself <sup>1</sup>.  While it's *possible* to get a Linux desktop running in WSL2 (see other answers), it's hacky and not needed to answer your particular question.

To fix the warnings, you may have to do a few things.  First, the "must have" -- Install the missing services.  The services that Emacs is trying to reach, according to the warnings, are:

- GIO:  The Gnome I/O Framework.  This is typically a dependency of applications that utilize GVFS (Gnome Virtual Filesystem), a service which allows end-users to access some virtual filesystems in user-space.  For example, the "Trashcan" feature in Ubuntu uses GVFS so that, when you delete a file from a GVFS/GIO application, it gets moved to the Trash instead of immediately removed forever.  Apparently, Emacs uses GIO and/or GVFS in some way (although I don't know if it uses the Trash function).
- AT-SPI:  The Assisted Technology Service Provider Interface.  I'll be honest -- I had to look this one up myself.  It's an interface for Accessibility features, such as screen readers, braille, eye-trackers, etc.  Without some higher level service (such as a screen-reader), it probably won't be used.  But that's the same with GIO, honestly -- Typically it's some higher-level functionality (like GVFS) that *uses* GIO.

So to resolve the error messages:

```
sudo apt install gvfs at-spi2-core
```

This will install GVFS (which will include GIO as a dependency) and AT-SPI.

Personally, I'm seeing a few other errors, but I think those are due to my own configuration issues, especially based on your comment.  For now, I'm editing the other error messages out of this answer.

---

<sup>*Footnotes*</sup>

<sup>1</sup> Technically, it's Weston, running an RDP/Rails shell that uses the Windows Remote Desktop client to view the application on the Windows desktop.  However, for most users, the end-result is simply that it looks like the Linux GUI application is running on the Windows desktop.

Comment: I installed the packages, and the errors are gone, and I don't get the `libGL` error or the wrong user permission issue. Do you have the Docker desktop with WSL integration? I remember the `/run/user/UID` issue is caused by the integration.

Comment: @DavidS. I do have Docker Desktop, but I after some debugging last night that it's (oddly) the fact that I have `tmux` as my shell in that distribution that is resetting `/run/user/`.  Not sure why that is, but I was just coming back to edit that part out of here, since most people won't have that corner case ;-).

Comment: Thanks. After I restart my laptop, I also got the `libGL error: MESA-LOADER` error. But it doesn't repeat until reboot.